# JobScheduler in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Do we have jobScheduler in cn1? If not, I'm trying to apply jobScheduler in cn1 through native interface. But it is giving java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - No such service ComponentInfo error. Have a look at the code and error log below. Thanks...

NativeImpl class

```
package com.capitaleyenepal.nokia;

import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.util.Log;
import com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class NativeImpl {
     JobScheduler jobScheduler;
     private static final int MYJOBID = 1;

    public boolean isSupported() {
         return true;
    }

    public void jobSchedulerMethod() {
        Context context = AndroidNativeUtil.getContext();
        Activity activity = AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity();
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) activity.getSystemService(context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        ComponentName jobService = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MyJobService.class.getName());
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService).setPeriodic(10000).build();

        int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
        if (jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo) > 0) {
            Log.e("job", "Successfully scheduled job: ");
        } else {
            Log.e("job", "RESULT_FAILURE: ");
        }
    }
}
```

MyJobService class

```
package com.capitaleyenepal.nokia;

import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    public MyJobService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "MyJobService.onStartJob()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "MyJobService.onStopJob()",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error while debugging

```
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/ResourcesManager﹕ Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.zzzz.nokiaoverlayDirs =Null
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.zzzz.nokia-1/lib/arm
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/ContextRelationManager﹕ ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia E/Qmage﹕ isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia E/Qmage﹕ isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia E/Qmage﹕ isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/ViewRootImpl﹕ #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4fe734e I.ED..... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/SecWifiDisplayUtil﹕ Metadata value : SecSettings2
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/ActivityThread﹕ AppLock checkAppLockState isAppLocked = false pkgName = com.zzzz.nokia showWhenLocked = false
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia I/Codename One﹕ Resource not found: theme_phone.ovr
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia I/Codename One﹕ Resource not found: theme_android.ovr
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia I/Codename One﹕ Resource not found: theme_android-phone.ovr
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/libEGL﹕ eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xde1717c4
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/ViewRootImpl﹕ MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp﹕ [EDT] 0:0:0,6 - Codename One revisions: 3b9f8bde8556aa9c6b782c0cd6b70adf3f27e7e5

09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp: [EDT] 0:4:46,666 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - No such service ComponentInfo{com.zzzz.nokia/com.zzzz.nokia.MyJobService}
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.zzzz.nokia/com.zzzz.nokia.MyJobService}
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1625)
09-04 16:33:41.505 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1574)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:121)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.zzzz.nokia.NativeImpl.jobSchedulerMethod(NativeImpl.java:40)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.zzzz.nokia.NativeStub.jobSchedulerMethod(NativeStub.java:9)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.zzzz.nokia.nokia.start(nokia.java:48)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.zzzz.nokia.nokiaStub.run(nokiaStub.java:140)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1056)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1000)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:901)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp: [EDT] 0:4:46,670 - Exception in NokiaApp version 1.0
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp: [EDT] 0:4:46,671 - OS and
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp: [EDT] 0:4:46,672 - Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{com.zzzz.nokia/com.zzzz.nokia.MyJobService}
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp: [EDT] 0:4:46,673 - Before the first form!

                                                                   [ 09-04 16:33:41.515  2644: 3009 I/         ]
                                                                   TimaKeyStore: /data/misc/tima_keystore/user_0/C857567C6CFBBB180D84E31D15498CDAB0315CC87FBA23774E2F91E0A820390F8677956B17547A46B5138121BDE4B511B5E7AC37AF059F7B91B0602356D552EA exists
09-04 16:33:41.515 5478-5495/com.zzzz.nokia D/NokiaApp: [EDT] 0:4:46,674 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - No such service ComponentInfo{com.zzzz.nokia/com.zzzz.nokia.MyJobService}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that the right package name? What did you define for the manifest inject etc? Where is the nokia string coming from?

Comment: yeahhh that is a right pakage name "com.zzzz.nokia" . I've jst replaced my company name with zzzz. Its project name is NokiaApp. I've jst used nokia string in my package name randomely. There's no permission needed for job scheduler.  Should I do anything with manifest?

Comment: If you build with include source is the file packaged there? Did you place it under native/android in the right package hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know why you are confused with the package names here. Have a look at the screenshots I've provided above in the question. I had just replaced "capitaleyenepal" with "zzzz" manually before.

Comment: Did you cut it out from the definition of `MyJobService`?

Comment: solved it... Forgot to add service in manifest (xapplication).